# How to efficiently avoid replacing a substring when there are string necessary to be replaced with python pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, substring

I would like to update the words/phrases with their link.

However, since the words phrases might be the substring of others, I am looking for an efficient method to replace all words/phrases without duplicate replacement.

**Substitution list**

An example of a : the following words/phrases need to be replaced with their corresponding markdown links after ">>":

1. ABC Apple     >> `[ABC Apple](http://abc_apple)`
2. ABC Apples    >> `[ABC Apples](http://abc_apples)`
3. Apple         >> `[Apple](http://apple)`
4. Apples        >> `[Apples](http://apples)`
5. Apple Pie     >> `[Apple Pie](http://apple_pie)`
6. Red Apple     >> `[Red Apple](http://red_apple)`
7. Red Apple Pie >> `[Red Apple Pie](http://red_apple_pie)`

**Idea**

When we have a data structure that each words/phrases (substring) store the words/phrases(string) that contain them (say list_l), we could check if a sentence contains element in list_l before check if it contains a substring

For example, now we have the following substring : {list_l(string)}

- ABC Apple : {ABC Apples}
- ABC Apples : {}
- Apple : {ABC Apple, ABC Apples, Apples, Apple Pie, Red Apple,Red Apple Pie}
- Apples : {}
- Apple Pie : {Red Apple Pie}
- Red Apple : {Red Apple Pie}
- Red Apple Pie : {}

However, the computational effort will be quiet much, since each element in list_l, we still need to check the list_l of that element.

**Examples**

Some sentences to be replaced as examples (walked through from backward):

1. "I love Apple Pie.": Red Apple Pie(x) >> Red Apple(x) >> Apple Pie(o) >> Red Apple Pie(x)
2. "I like ABC Apple!": Red Apple Pie(x) >> Red Apple(x) >> Apple Pie(x) >> Apples(x) >> Apple(o) >> Red Apple Pie(x) >> Red Apple(x) >> Red Apple Pie(x) >> Apple Pie(x) >> Red Apple Pie(x) >> Apples(x) >> ABC Apples (x) >> ABC Apple (o) >> ABC Apples(x)

Computational effort O(n^3)
length of sentence x length of substitution list x length of list_l

(Original sentence >> result sentence:)

**Expected result**:

```
"I like ABC Apple!"` >> `"I like [ABC Apple](http://abc_apple)!"
```

**Wrong result**:

```
"I like ABC Apple!"` >> `"I like ABC [Apple](http://apple)!"
```

Comment: Does the obvious not work? Process the list of substitutions from longest to shortest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a greedy naive O(MN + MlogM) solution (N size of string and M size of all substitutions).

The first passage is to sort the possible substitution by length (O(MlogM)).

Then you search in the original sentence a substitution and in case is found you do the replacement (O(N)). You need to do this for every substitution and in order; so is O(MN)

The fact that you search in order should solve (if I understood well) your problem. 
To maintain the complexity above in the development you'll probably need some tricks to not read an "already made replacement", but it shouldn't be too difficult. 
In the end I think that there can be solution with a lower time complexity using some datastructures, but way more difficult to implement